# What is the best way to update a department name in Active Directory and Azure for 100+ users?

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory

Azure is currently setup to sync from on
prem. Active Directory. What is the best way to update the department name
in Active Directory and Azure for these users? Below is a sample of the list.

| Name | Old Department Name | New Department Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Larry Lue | Collections | Collector Members |
| Erica Anderson | Collections | Collector Members |
| Mary Lee | Collections | Collector Members |

Comment: microsoft recommend to migrate on-prem ad to Azure AD, then you can manage user information by ms graph api

Answer (score 0):

You can use ms graph api to do the update by code. But [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) doesn't provide a batch operation, so you have to update user profile one by one. Here's my test result:

Before updating the department, the original department look like this:

[image]

After update it by code. it will be changed to the new value.

Here's the code snippet:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
    var clientId = "azure_ad_app_id";
    var clientSecret = "azure_ad_app_client_secret";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    
    //query user information
    var user = await graphClient.Users["user_id"]
        .Request().Select("displayname, department").GetAsync();

    //update user information
    var userDept = new User
    {
        Department = "Collector Members"
    };
    await graphClient.Users["9a8ae89f-711a-434a-8d08-43e1f7d29af2"]
        .Request()
        .UpdateAsync(userDept);
}
```